# C++ Doubly linked list, including benchmark vs std::list

Tags: c++, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel, c++20

I wrote a rudimentary implementation of doubly linked list.

Feel free to comment anything!

```
#ifndef __CLRS4_LINKED_LIST_H__
#define __CLRS4_LINKED_LIST_H__

#include <common.h>
#include <concepts>
#include <iterator>

namespace frozenca::hard {

using namespace std;

template <typename T> class ListNode {
public:
  T key_ = {};
  ListNode *prev_ = nullptr;
  ListNode *next_ = nullptr;
  ListNode() = default; 
  ListNode(const T &key) : key_{key} {}
  ListNode(const ListNode &other) = delete;
  ListNode &operator=(const ListNode &other) = delete;
};

template <typename T, bool Const> class ListIterator {
public:
  using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
  using value_type = T;
  using pointer = conditional_t<Const, const T*, T*>;
  using reference = conditional_t<Const, const T&, T&>;
  using iterator_category = bidirectional_iterator_tag;
  using iterator_concept = iterator_category;
  using node = ListNode<T>*;

public: 
  node node_ = nullptr;
  
  ListIterator() = default;
  ListIterator(node node) : node_{node} {}

  ListIterator(const ListIterator<T, false>& other) requires (Const) : node_{other.node_} {}

  ListIterator(const ListIterator& other) = default;
  ListIterator& operator=(const ListIterator& other) = default;
  ListIterator (ListIterator&& other) noexcept = default;
  ListIterator& operator=(ListIterator&& other) noexcept = default;

  reference operator*() const noexcept {
    return node_->key_;
  }

  pointer operator->() const noexcept {
    return &(node_->key_);
  }

  ListIterator& operator++() {
    node_ = node_->next_;
    return *this;  
  }

  ListIterator operator++(int) {
    ListIterator temp = *this;
    node_ = node_->next_;
    return temp;
  }

  ListIterator& operator--() {
    node_ = node_->prev_;
    return *this;  
  }

  ListIterator operator--(int) {
    ListIterator temp = *this;
    node_ = node_->prev_;
    return temp;
  }

  [[nodiscard]] friend bool operator==(const ListIterator& lhs, const ListIterator& rhs) {
    return lhs.node_ == rhs.node_;
  }

  node get_node() const {
    return node_;
  }
  
};

template <typename T> class LinkedList {
  using Node = ListNode<T>;

  Node *head_ = nullptr; // sentinel node
  ptrdiff_t size_ = 0;

public:
  using value_type = T;
  using reference_type = T&;
  using const_reference_type = const T&;
  using iterator_type = ListIterator<T, false>;
  using const_iterator_type = ListIterator<T, true>;
  using reverse_iterator_type = reverse_iterator<iterator_type>;
  using const_reverse_iterator_type = reverse_iterator<const_iterator_type>;

  LinkedList() : head_(new Node()) {
    head_->next_ = head_;
    head_->prev_ = head_;
  }
  LinkedList(const LinkedList &l) : head_(new Node()) {
    head_->next_ = head_;
    head_->prev_ = head_;
    for (const auto& val : l) {
      push_back(val);
    }
  }
  LinkedList &operator=(const LinkedList &l) {
    clear();
    for (const auto& val : l) {
      push_back(val);
    }
    return *this;
  }
  LinkedList(LinkedList &&l) : head_{move(l.head_)} {}
  LinkedList &operator=(LinkedList &&l) {
    destroy();
    head_ = move(l.head_);
    return *this;
  }

private:
  void destroy() {
    head_->prev_->next_ = nullptr;
    auto curr = head_->next_;
    while (curr) {
      auto next = curr->next_;
      delete curr;
      curr = next;
    }
    delete head_;
  }

public:
  ~LinkedList() {
    destroy();
  }

  [[nodiscard]] reference_type front() noexcept {
    return head_->next_->key_;
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_reference_type front() const noexcept {
    return head_->next_->key_;
  }

  [[nodiscard]] reference_type back() noexcept {
    return head_->prev_->key_;
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_reference_type back() const noexcept {
    return head_->prev_->key_;
  }

  [[nodiscard]] iterator_type begin() noexcept {
    return iterator_type(head_->next_);
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_iterator_type begin() const noexcept {
    return const_iterator_type(head_->next_);
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_iterator_type cbegin() const noexcept {
    return const_iterator_type(head_->next_);
  }

  [[nodiscard]] iterator_type end() noexcept {
    return iterator_type(head_);
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_iterator_type end() const noexcept {
    return const_iterator_type(head_);
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_iterator_type cend() const noexcept {
    return const_iterator_type(head_);
  }

  [[nodiscard]] reverse_iterator_type rbegin() noexcept {
    return reverse_iterator_type(end());
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_reverse_iterator_type rbegin() const noexcept {
    return const_reverse_iterator_type(end());
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_reverse_iterator_type crbegin() const noexcept {
    return const_reverse_iterator_type(end());
  }

  [[nodiscard]] reverse_iterator_type rend() noexcept {
    return reverse_iterator_type(begin());
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_reverse_iterator_type rend() const noexcept {
    return const_reverse_iterator_type(begin());
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_reverse_iterator_type crend() const noexcept {
    return const_reverse_iterator_type(begin());
  }

  [[nodiscard]] bool empty() const noexcept {
    return size_ == 0;
  }

  [[nodiscard]] ptrdiff_t size() const noexcept {
    return size_;
  }

  void clear() noexcept {
    head_->prev_->next_ = nullptr;
    auto curr = head_->next_;
    while (curr) {
      auto next = curr->next_;
      delete curr;
      curr = next;
    }
    head_->next_ = head_;
    head_->prev_ = head_;
    size_ = 0;
  }

private:
  void insert_before(Node* where, const T& value) {
    auto node = new Node(value);
    node->next_ = where;
    node->prev_ = where->prev_;
    where->prev_->next_ = node;
    where->prev_ = node;
    ++size_;
  }

  void erase_at(Node* where) {
    where->prev_->next_ = where->next_;
    where->next_->prev_ = where->prev_;
    delete where;
    --size_;
  }

public:
  iterator_type insert(const_iterator_type pos, const T& value) {
    auto where = pos.get_node();
    insert_before(where, value);
    return iterator_type(where->prev_);
  }

  iterator_type erase(iterator_type pos) {
    auto where = pos.get_node();
    if (where == head_) {
      throw invalid_argument("attempt to erase at end()\n");
    }
    auto next = where->next_;
    erase_at(where);
    return iterator_type(next);
  }

  void push_back(const T& value) {
    insert_before(head_, value);
  }

  void push_front(const T& value) {
    insert_before(head_->next_, value);
  }

  void pop_back() {
    erase_at(head_->prev_);
  }

  void pop_front() {
    erase_at(head_->next_);
  }

};

} // namespace frozenca::hard

#endif //__CLRS4_LINKED_LIST_H__
```

Test code (Basic):

```
frozenca::hard::LinkedList<int> l;
l.push_back(3);
l.push_front(2);
l.push_front(6);
l.push_back(4);

// 6 2 3 4
for (auto num : l) {
  std::cout << num << ' ';
}
```

Test code (Benchmark):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <linkedlist.h>
#include <list>
#include <random>
#include <ranges>
#include <test.h>
#include <util.h>
#include <vector>

namespace fc = frozenca;
using namespace std;

template <typename ListType> void linked_list_test() {
  constexpr int max_n = 5'000;
  constexpr int max_trials = 200;

  // 1. insert max_n random elements in the doubly linked list, maintaining sorted order.
  // 2. For max_n random elements, erase it if it exists in the list.
  
  mt19937 gen(random_device{}());
  uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, max_n);
  vector<float> durations_insert;
  vector<float> durations_erase;
  for (int t = 0; t < max_trials; ++t) {
    ListType l;

    float duration = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < max_n; ++i) {
      auto num = dist(gen);
      auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
      l.insert(ranges::lower_bound(l, num), num);
      if (!ranges::is_sorted(l)) {
        cout << "Verification fail!\n";
      }
      auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
      duration +=
          chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<float, micro>>(end - start)
              .count();
    }
    durations_insert.push_back(duration);

    duration = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < max_n; ++i) {
      auto num = dist(gen);
      auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
      auto it = ranges::find(l, num);
      if (it != ranges::end(l)) {
        l.erase(it);
        if (!ranges::is_sorted(l)) {
          cout << "Verification fail!\n";
        }
      }
      auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
      duration +=
          chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<float, micro>>(end - start)
              .count();
    }
    durations_erase.push_back(duration);
  }
  {
    auto stat = fc::get_statistics(durations_insert);
    fc::log("Time to insert {:6} elements:\n"
            "Average : {:10.4f} us,\n"
            "Stdev   : {:10.4f} us,\n"
            "95%     : {:10.4f} us,\n"
            "99%     : {:10.4f} us,\n"
            "99.9%   : {:10.4f} us,\n",
            fc::log_level::all, max_n, stat.average, stat.stdev,
            stat.percentile_95, stat.percentile_99, stat.percentile_999);
  }
  {
    auto stat = fc::get_statistics(durations_erase);
    fc::log("Time to erase {:6} elements:\n"
            "Average : {:10.4f} us,\n"
            "Stdev   : {:10.4f} us,\n"
            "95%     : {:10.4f} us,\n"
            "99%     : {:10.4f} us,\n"
            "99.9%   : {:10.4f} us,\n",
            fc::log_level::all, max_n, stat.average, stat.stdev,
            stat.percentile_95, stat.percentile_99, stat.percentile_999);
  }
}

int main() {
  cout << "Linked list demo\n";
  cout << "frozenca::hard::LinkedList<int> test\n";
  linked_list_test<fc::hard::LinkedList<int>>();
  cout << "std::list<int> test\n";
  linked_list_test<list<int>>();
}
```

Benchmark result: (vs MSVC 19.30 implementation, maximum optimization)

```
Linked list demo
frozenca::hard::LinkedList<int> test
Time to insert   5000 elements:
Average : 71844.2578 us,
Stdev   :  7444.8242 us,
95%     : 88561.5234 us,
99%     : 101742.2500 us,
99.9%   : 113460.9453 us,

Time to erase   5000 elements:
Average : 97494.5938 us,
Stdev   : 10818.2012 us,
95%     : 121672.1406 us,
99%     : 139435.2031 us,
99.9%   : 140593.4844 us,

std::list<int> test
Time to insert   5000 elements:
Average : 70630.7734 us,
Stdev   :  4279.7686 us,
95%     : 80608.0859 us,
99%     : 88774.6719 us,
99.9%   : 88923.8906 us,

Time to erase   5000 elements:
Average : 97779.0469 us,
Stdev   :  5760.7676 us,
95%     : 111651.0078 us,
99%     : 118270.0703 us,
99.9%   : 123327.6562 us,
```

My average time consumption is roughly similar with MSVC implementation,
but my implementation has much bigger standard deviation.. I don't know why

Comment: `using namespace std;` in a header is an instant rejection from me.  I guess it could be worse - it's only polluting `frozenca` and not the global namespace.  But it's still harmful.

Comment: @Toby Speight Why it´s stil harmful? Could you explain?

Comment: @convert: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @Toby Speight I know, have read it long ago, but since you said " it's only polluting frozenca", it should be no problem.

Comment: “… it should be no problem.” Such charming optimism. I shall remember it when we dance around the flames of this code, the day that (for example) C++69 defines a `std::push_back()` free function that takes a single parameter, and is unambiguously a better match than the member function as used in the copy constructor, leaving all users of the class baffled about why recompiling their code on a new compiler, despite producing no warnings or errors, suddenly causes all their list copies to be empty.

Comment: By the by, “… my implementation has much bigger standard deviation.. I don't know why…” I note that in your benchmark program, you run the benchmarks on your class first. Try flipping the order around. This could be a simple case of RAM access, caches, branch predictors, etc. simply being “cold” when the program starts up, then being “heated up” by the first set of tests, so the first few iterations are abnormally long. Benchmarking is *hard*.

Answer (score 2):

## Hide `ListNode` and `ListIterator`

These classes are implementation details of `LinkedList`. Consider hiding them in some way, to avoid polluting the namespace (what if you want to add a `ForwardList`, what is its node type going to be?) and to avoid risking code starting to use the internal types directly.

One way would be to nest them inside `LinkedList`, which is my personal favorite, but there might be some minor drawbacks. Another way is to put them into a `namespace detail`.

## Derive `const`ness from `T`

Your `ListIterator` has a template parameter `Const`, but consider that you can check if `T` itself is `const` or not using [`std::is_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const).

## Store `head_` by value

Interesting choice of making `head` a sentinel and using it to store the head and tail of the list. However, there is no reason to allocate it on the heap, just store it by value. There is another problem with this approach though:

## What if `T` does not have a default constructor?

It is a bit unfortunate, but the fact that you use a `Node` to store the head and tail pointers also means you are default-constructing a `T`. Now consider a `T` that doesn't have a default constructor.

I think you should resort to having separate head and tail pointers that are not doubling as sentinels.

## Consider using `std::unique_ptr`

You are manually allocating memory. While I don't see any issue in your implementation, you could've used `std::unique_ptr` for `next_`, and keep `prev_` a regular pointer.

Comment: Just one example where not using `std::unique_ptr` leads to problems, consider the copy constructor. That allocates the sentinel, then calls `push_back()` for every item in the source list. `push_back()` in turn calls `insert_before()`, which allocates a new node while copying the value into it. If that copy throws, the allocation of the new node is undone… but every other node that has been allocated, and the sentinel, all leak.

Comment: There’s also the issue that moving raw pointers does not work like moving `unique_ptr`s, meaning that if you actually move construct a list, you’ll eventually end up with a double delete. Basically there’s a whole flotilla of problems here due to not using smart pointers.

Comment: ```const```ness of ```ListIterator``` is little bit different from that of ```T```, so I can't use ```const```ness of ```T``` directly. But it would be okay to change ```using iterator_type = ListIterator<T, false>;``` to ```using iterator_type = ListIterator<remove_cvref_t<T>, is_const_v<T>>;```

Comment: For using ```std::unique_ptr```, this is basically circular doubly linked list, so using ```std::unique_ptr``` for ```next_``` will complicate implementation too much.. But thanks for good catch for problems in copy constructors and move constructors. They should be definitely fixed

Comment: And minor mistake, I missed that ```destroy()``` should include ```size_ = 0;```

Comment: For the cases that ```T``` is not default constructible, I found that instead of using ```head_ {new Node()}```, using ```head_ {allocator<Node>{}.allocate(1)}``` does the job

Comment: Ah, `allocate()` might work, but then don't forget to `deallocate()` instead of `delete` of course.